# Search for (LaTeX) regex found NOT within another regex (math mode)

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to find all improperly-written commands in LaTeX that are NOT within math mode. That is, in the following, I want to match "\bad" but NOT "\good\" or "\math".

```
Example of \bad command. Example of \good\ command. And $x=\math + y$ is also a good command.
```

I figured out how to match math mode, which begins and ends with non-escaped dollar signs "$" -- I essentially want to invert this match somehow:

```
(?<!\\)\$.+?[^\\]\$
```

And I figured out how to match "\bad" but not "\good\" (note the space after the +):

```
\\[A-Za-z]+
```

But I can't figure out how to combine the two. I've tried (negative) lookarounds and don't seem to be getting anywhere (not every paragraph necessarily contains math mode). Any suggestions/hints? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

1. I'm using Perl-compatible regex (Sublime Text 3, to be exact).
2. A "bad" command is a macro NOT within math mode, followed by a space. A "good" command is a macro followed by anything else -- punctuation or backslash -- or any macro within math mode.

Comment: You have to: 1. say what language/regex flavor you're using, 2. explain how to tell a good command from a bad command (as not everyone is familiar enough with regex *and* latex).

Comment: So having a macro outside of math mode is "bad"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime Text uses the Boost library to handle regexes, so it's not fully Perl-compatible.

The true Perl-compatible answer would be:

```
\$.*?\$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\\w+(?=\s)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xO9bS2/1)

But you can't use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick with Boost, unfortunately (until [this feature request](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11205) get implemented).

You can work around this somehow like that:

```
\$.*?\$\K|\\\w+(?(?=\s)|\K)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL5sK6/1)

The problem with this approach is that *"bad"* commands and math mode end markers will *still* yield an empty (zero-length) match (thanks to `\K`). I don't know if that's good enough for you.

Comment: It would be ideal if it did not match those as zero-length so I can just use Sublime Text.  But I can always just test for these using Perl itself, that's fine!  Thanks so much, this is greatly helpful, love the demos!  I didn't know about the (*SKIP) or (*FAIL), and \K evaded my memory.

Comment: Happy to help. If you want to know more about `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` you can read this [in-depth explanation](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Comment: Great article (I read the whole thing)!  I have a Perl script that works beautifully.  Thanks again